# parsing csv in python and writing in other csv, yes is choice present and no if choice absent

Tags: python, csv, parsing

Input (`new.csv`:)

```
student Jack

Choice Phy

Choice Chem

Choice  Maths

Choice  Biology

student Jill

Choice  Phy

Choice  Biology

Choice  Maths
```

Expected Output (`out.csv`)

```
Student  Phy     Chem   Maths   Biology

Jack     Yes     Yes      Yes   Yes

Jill    Yes      No       Yes   Yes
```

Parsing `new.csv` and writing result in `out.csv`.For each student name, writing `YES` if a choice of subject is present and `NO` if the subject is not in the choice(subjects become new header in out.csv). 
Here I have used nested if to get desired output.Please help me with better pythonic way of code.
I am newbie to python.Eager to learn better way of coding.
P.S: Choice of subjects is not in the same order.

```
import csv
la =[]
l2=[]
with open("new.csv","r",newline='\n') as k:
     k=csv.reader(k, delimiter=',', quotechar='_', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
     counter = 0
     for col in k :
           # number of rows in csv is 600      
            if counter<=600:

                if col[0] =='student':

                        la.append("\n "+col[1])
                        a=next(k) 


                       if a[1] == 'Phy':
                            la.append('yes')
                            a = next(k)

                        else:
                            la.append('no')

                        if a[1] == 'Chem':
                             la.append('yes')
                             a = next(k)
                        else:
                             la.append('no')

                        if a[1] == 'Maths':
                           la.append('yes')
                           a = next(k)
                        else:
                             la.append('no')

                        if a[1] == 'Biology':
                            la.append('yes')
                            a = next(k)
                            counter += 1

                        else:
                            la.append('no')
                            counter += 1        

l2=",".join(la)

with open("out.csv","w") as w:
    w.writelines(l2)
```

Comment: Does your code have a problem? If yes, let us know what problem.

Comment: Divya, do you have a question? If yes, state it explicitly.

Comment: This would be a good case for learning how to use `itertools.groupby` - not an easy method for Python beginners, but very pythonic way to loop through records in groups, which it looks like what you have.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it is time to learn how to debug simple prorams. Some IDE come with nice debuggers, but you can still use the good old `pdb` or simply add print traces in your code to easily understand what happens.

Here, the first and most evident problem is here:

```
tot = sum(1 for col in k)
```

It is pretty useless because `for col in k` would be enough, but it consumes the totality of the `k` iterator, so the next line `for col in k:` try to access an iterator that has already reached its end and the loop immediately stops.

That is not all:

- first line contains `Student` with an upper case `S` while you test `student` with a lower case `s`: they are different strings... This case problems exists on all the other comparisons.
- when you find `student`, you set `a` to the line following it... and never change it. So even if you fix your case errors, you will consistently use that only line for the student!

If you are a beginner, the rule is *Keep It Simple, Stupid*. So start from something you can control and then start to add other features:

1. read the input file with the csv module and just print the list for every row. Do not step further until this gives what you want! That would have stopped you from the `tot = sum(1 for col in k)` error...
2. identify every student. Just print it first, then store its name in a list and print the list after the loop
3. identify subject. Just print them first, then feed a dictionnary with the subjects
4. wonder how you can get that at the end of the loop...
5. just realize that you could store the student name in that dictionnary, and put the full dictionnary in the list (feel free to ask a new question if you are stuck there...)
6. print the list of dictionnaries at the end of the loop
7. build one row for student that could feed the csv writer, or as you already have a list of dict, considere using a `DictWriter`.

Good luck in practicing Python!

---

Here is a possible way for the read part:

```
import csv

la = {}       # use a dict to use the student name as index

with open("new.csv","r",newline='\n') as k:
    k=csv.reader(k, delimiter=',', quotechar='_', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    # counter = 0 # pretty useless...
    for col in k :
        if col[0] =='student':
            l2 = set()        # initialize a set to store subjects
            la[col[1]] = l2   # reference it in la indexed by the student's name
        else:                 # it should be a subject line
            l2.add(col[1])    # note the subject

# Ok la is a dict with studend names as key, and a set containing subjects for that student as value
print(la)
```

For the write part, you should:

- build an union of all sets to get all the possible subjects (unless you know that)
- for each item (name, subjects) from la, build a list storing yes or no for each of the possible subject
- write that list to the output csv file

...left as an exercise...

Comment: Few case-sensitive errors like student occurred ,apologies for that.I have used number of rows in csv  and counter to iterate over each row.Thanks for suggestion about dictionaries.I tried something like{ name:[list of marks]} but could not proceed.

Comment: @divyalakshmi: You still have case errors in your code. See my edit for some more hints...